# OpenGL Causes PySide6/PyQt6 Application to Reload itself

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, pyqt6, qtopengl

When adding (at runtime) a new widget that carries any OpenGl component or is in itself an OpenGL widget(for example QOpenGLWidget), the application 'reloads' itself. Only after the 'reload' does it show the OpenGL widget. Even though the application 'reloads' it appears to maintain the previous application state as far as I have noticed.

**Problems caused/noticed**

- If the application was running a process using QProcess, and then i add the new 3d-widget while the process was still running, the "reload" will kill the process.
- the application 'reloading' breaks the user experience

**Sample Example**

The provided code example uses [pyqtgraph](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/)to render 3d objects.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QMainWindow, QWidget
import sys 
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        w = QWidget()
        self.wLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setWindowTitle("OpenGL widget Error")
        self.state = QLabel("Before adding open gl, window effect intact")
        self.addWButton = QPushButton("add 3d widget")
        self.addWButton.clicked.connect(self.add3DWidget)
        self.wLayout.addWidget(self.state)
        self.wLayout.addWidget(self.addWButton)
        w.setLayout(self.wLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def add3DWidget(self):
        w3d = gl.GLViewWidget()
        self.wLayout.addWidget(w3d)
        self.state.setText("After adding opengl widget, application reloads")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**My Envronment**

- Windows 11
- Python: 3.10.7 64-bit
- PySide6: 6.4.2

This 'reload' happens when using PySide6 or PyQt6. When tested on PyQt5, the reload does not occur. I have not tested with other versions of PySide or PyQt.

Why does this happen and how can it be prevent it from happening?

Assitance will be very much appreciated.

**Edit as adviced by @musicamante**

Here is a screencapture for pyqt5 and pyqt6 respectively.

Window behaviour with pyqt5

[image: Window behaviour with pyqt5]

Window behaviour with pyqt6

[image: Window behaviour with pyqt6]

Comment: It's literally impossible that the application "reloads". What's more likely is that the *window* (which is **not** the "application") gets "flushed" and may flicker for a fraction of a second due to the addition of an overlay surface, which is a **completely different** thing. Please provide a screen capture of the result you're experiencing, as right now the concept of "reload" means absolutely nothing to us.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for this. You are correct, it is the window and not the application. Apologies for my poor wording. I have added the requested screen captures.

Comment: I bet if you added the widget in the init, kept a class ref for it then disabled it, then enabled it on button click, it won't flicker. (`self.w3d.setEnabled(False)`) Although, this seems to be unexpected behaviour for PySide 6.